# How to parse this AJAX response in Handlebars?

Tags: jquery, ajax, handlebars.js

I am trying to parse out an AJAX response into a handlebars template and not quite sure how to get it working. Here is the response I am getting:

```
{"results":[{"location":"Northwest","sort":0,"rep":[{"name":"Bill Murray","title":"Owner","area":"Seattle, WA","phone":"(555) 555-5555","email":"billmurray@me.com","warehouse":{"manager":"Bill Davidson","address":"555 Loring Way","city":"Seattle","state":"WA","postal_code":"55555","phone":"(555) 555-5555"}}]}]}
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
{{#each location}}
    {{ rep.name }}
    {{ rep.title }}
    {{ rep.area }}
{{/each}}
```

Sorry, still very new to this AJAX stuff!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have an array called 'location', but rather your top level array is called 'results', so your first #each call needs to pass 'results'.  'rep' is not an object literal, but an array, so it must be iterated with an #each call as well:

```
{{#each results}}
    {{#each rep}}
        {{ name }}
        {{ title }}
        {{ area }}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```